# Changing Guardian Appearance In Destiny

Tags: destiny

Is there a way to change your appearance after you have already created your character? I have a level 33 Awoken Hunter and I don't like the way he looks. I'm playing on Xbox One if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately you can't change the look of your character. The only option you have is to delete your character and start over.